# Careers: add ability to hide some information on public profile

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs, profile-page, security

This week I was contacted directly by a recruiter who managed to figure out my e-mail from some combination of my StackOverflow careers page and my gravatar.

For people with alumni email addresses, it would help to let them hide their Education history in their public profile (I still want employers to see it though).

I know that [having a gravatar makes it easy to confirm my email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912722/112705) once you've guessed it, but I'd like to make it a little harder to guess.  I've seen the [FindGitHubEmail](https://github.com/hodgesmr/FindGitHubEmail) tool, which I imagine you could combine with education history to guess alumni emails pretty effectively.

It sucks that you're missing out on revenue from recruiters who are bypassing the paid system like this.

Comment: Gravatar's are now hashed, but some users haven't refreshed their gravatar image to take advantage of it.

Comment: But hiding information like your University education would take a lot of value away from your profile, wouldn't it? I imagine many people would not want to do that. Plus, chances are that many candidates' mail addresses can be found elsewhere on the net. I think some amount of recruiter sneakery Careers will simply have to live with.

Comment: I was hoping for a feature where the user could choose what to show/hide on their public careers page (similar to the way LinkedIn does it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used to have this functionality, but removed it about a year and a half ago because our primary goal for your profile is to be a listing of all the awesome things you've done, not a tool for customizing your resumes.  This change coincided with the ability to actually create customized resumes using the pdf resume generator which you can find on the right side of your profile edit page or when you are using the apply with your profile feature.

Another major factor in that decision was that it was confusing for many people to know what was showing up where and how each of those different views were used.  This caused us a lot of headaches on the support side, despite having each view labeled in the navigation when viewing your profile.  Now it's simple, this is what your profile looks like all the time.

I agree it sucks that people have developed ways to figure out your email address from publicly available information, but I'm pretty confident in saying those people would never have been our customers anyway and we're not missing out on any revenue as a result thereof.  Also, there are better ways for us to address this specific issue than introducing a large amount of confusion (and maintenance codewise, having been through that already).  For instance, the rest of the SE network allows you to upload your image directly through us.  Careers should support this functionality as well; we should have supported it since the rest of the network went that direction.

The fact that university email addresses are particularly easy to guess is a harder problem, but no harder than figuring out your email address at your current job which is probably as easy as just calling the front desk and asking for it directly (or a small amount of social engineering).  So then the question is how much would you have to hide to avoid being contacted?  And honestly, the point is to get contacted, it just sucks that the wrong person found you and they used shitty means to do it.